# What's your favorite dummy line to put a break point on?

Tags: debugging

Few of us would deny the awesomeness of debuggers, but to make it more useful, some tricks can be used.

For example in Python, you can use ***pass*** to do absolutely nothing except to leave you room to put a break point and allow you to observe the values in the Watch window.

In C#, I used to do ***GC.Collect()***, but now I use ***if (false){}***

What's your most playful dummy line?

Comment: WHy would you need a dummy line to put a breakpoint on ?  When can't you use an actual line ?

Comment: Charles, some lines get compiled out in the IL, so there is no place to place a breakpoint on. However,.NET in debug mode will insert a NOP statement in their place, so you can still break on them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In C#, you can use this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

It will force a breakpoint.

Comment: FWIW, it is similar to `debugger;` statement in JavaScript.

Comment: It's odd that this was accepted as the answer, since it doesn't address the actual question, which was about a line one can put a breakpoint on. Forcing a breakpoint is a quite different matter.

Answer (score 17):

In C#, in Visual Studio

```
{}
```

or

```
;
```

Comment: This is the best solution, I think. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Nice- thank you. I have been using int i=0, and the compiler always complains about those blank assignments.

Answer (score 8):

[Debug.Assert(true);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx), which automatically gets compiled out of release builds.

Answer (score 5):

```
volatile int e = 9;
```

Volatile means the compiler won't remove it because I don't read the variable.
'9' just so that it is non-zero.  Zero is too common for my tastes.

Comment: Many programmers would use 42

Comment: @tehp - But that's another key press and I'm a lazy engineer!  WHINE!

Answer (score 2):

in gcc/g++:

```
assert("breakpoint");
```

since any non-0/null value to an assert is taken as true.

or even

```
__asm__("nop");
```

at least I know there will be an instruction byte emitted for the breakpoint to occur on. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
int x = 0;
```

I always make sure I remove this line when I'm done debugging.

Comment: see my answer, but you should add 'volatile' to make sure the compiler doesn't remove it.

Comment: This won't work if you have the `Treat Warnings As Errors` setting enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I've never written something specifically to break on, but if I did, I'd write

```
int moot;
```

I use this one when there is some required 'out' parameter that I don't care about but must provide.

Answer (score 2):

For C/C++ I use

```
__asm int 3;
```

That will generate a breakpoint exception at that line of code which the debugger will catch. A caveat though is your program will crash with that exception if it's not being run inside a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

In VB6, I use a colon, by itself.  `:`

Answer (score 1):

In c++ I use

```
Sleep(0)
```

sometimes, or just find a variable that's used and assign it to itself:

```
i = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

True, it's strange that VS2010 debugger shifts breakpoints around if they are on an empty statement such as a semicolon. Despite what it looks like, in a debug build you can still generally put a breakpoint on an empty C# control block or semicolon, and it will get hit correctly. After being annoyed by this for a while, I just created this to use instead:

```
public static class Nop { public static void X() { } };
```

edit: To use it, put Nop.X() in your code...

Comment: @NoonSilk, regarding the required 'out' parameter, I also use a helper function when I don't want to return a value: "return Failed(out fn_out_param);" where fn_out_param is the 'out' parameter of the containing function, and the 'Failed' function just sets the out parameter to nothing. This keeps the return statment in the function I care about to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sophisticated, but functional.

```
bool bp;

bp = true; //whereever I need to break.
```